# VPS vs Cloud hosting, host on cloud

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I am able to develop angular/spring/postgres application, have basic understanding of kubernetes (minikube). And now its time to host application to cloud, and here I am total noob. Login to aws and there a a lot of services, pricing models etc. for me its hard to follow. I don't care if its aws, azure, google cloud or whatever. Mainly I want to run instances for front-end, back-end in a k8s cluster, configure database. Any guide would be helpful. Also what's the difference between VPS and Cloud hosting what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

> Any guide would be helpful. Also what's the difference between VPS and
> Cloud hosting what should I use?

You can use the services **AWS EKS** and **Google GKE** to easy **Kubernetes** setup. Instead of getting into much in VPS.

Cloud providers give you services that are easy to configure and directly usable **without** much configuration and management.

While in VPS virtual private server you might need to install the dependency, configure the network, and other lots of things to start basic Kubernetes.

The benefit of using a cloud provider like AWS, GCP (Google) they give managed services for **Kubernetes**, **Database**, **Storage** etc.

So you can configure the things just in a few clicks and start using them in  min.

i would recommend using the **GKE** **Google** for a very easy **Kubernetes** setup and using it.

Google is faster provisioning Kubernetes cluster for you in a few clicks only and you can access using the **Kubectl**